# Python: Natural language processing "vaderSentiment" import "sentiment" Error

Tags: python, text, import, nltk, package

I am using Python 3.5 in Jupyter Notebook (Anaconda 4.2).  I first downloaded the nltk Python package using the code below:

```
nltk.download()
```

I then selected and installed vader_lexicon from the pop up menu.  Please see image below.

[image]

However, when I run the following code:

```
import nltk 
import nltk.data
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import sentiment as vaderSentiment
```

I get the error (see image):

[image]

I have literally spent hours trying to fix this error over and over.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vadarSentiment does not have sentiment module.

the import should be:

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
```

source https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment/tree/master/vaderSentiment

Comment: @orsonady, how about calculating sentiment using your above answer. Please can you elaborate